# Intellij shortcut - how to open at project view current class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, shortcut

I just want to know if it is possible at Intellij open `Project view` for class which is currently opened. Using short cut.

***Steps:***

- After using find class shortcut (`Ctrl`+`N`) => type `String`
- Press `String` class from JDK. It has next looking:

[image]

- And now when press `Alt`+`1` => It will open `Project view` where it was active last time.
- But I want to know how to open this view and cursor is exactly at this class location:

[image]

I tried to find it at internet but without success.

***Any suggestions?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click the settings icon in the project view and check *Autoscroll from source*. That way any class (or any file for that matter) you open will be automatically selected in the project view.

[image]

or if you don't want this to happen always you can click this icon to naviage to the currently opened item in the project view:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't see any command in keymap section to bind this action to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: For the person who wants to bind this with keys, the name is 'Select File in Project View'

Answer (score 0):

Replying to an old thread, but may help someone in the future.
I am using IntelliJ 2020.2 and now I can see a keymap for the 'Select Opened File' (earlier 'Scroll from Source') button mentioned by @Bohuslav Burghardt. It's

> Alt + F1 and then 1 (submenu item 1)

[image]